# Как сделать, чтобы текст не заезжал под аватарку?

Tags: css

Сделал комментарии:

[image]

На телефоне текст комментария заезжает под аватарку:

[image]

Как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

приблизительно так

http://jsfiddle.net/5rkmy3ga/